# Insert into resursive array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm a php newbie. I need a dynamic menu so I'm trying to insert an array into another recursive array. But it doesn't seem to add anything. Basically the menu is an array with more arrays in it and every submenu has a parent id

Been messing around with it for a few days now and I'm pretty sure I keep missing something important

```
$items= [
    // ID => TITLE, URL, PARENT ID
    0 => ['menu 1', '', -1],
    1 => ['menu 2', '', -1],
    2 => ['menu 3', '', -1],
    3 => ['submenu 1.1', '', 0],
    4 => ['submenu 1.2', '', 0],
    5 => ['submenu 2.1', '', 1],
    6 => ['submenu 2.2', '', 1]
    ];
    
$menu = [];
    
fillMenu($menu, $items);


function fillMenu($menu, $items)
{
    foreach ($items as $key => $arr) {
    addMenuItem($menu, $key, $arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]);
    }
}
    
function addMenuItem($menu, $id, $title, $url, $parent_id)
{
    $m = [$title, $url, $parent_id];

    global $menu;

    $id_counter = 0;

    if ($parent_id === -1) {  // top menu layer
        array_push($menu, [$id++ => $m]);
    }
    else {
        insertSubmenu($id++, $menu, $m);
    }
}

function insertSubmenu($id, $menu, $submenu)
{
    foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {

            if ($key === $submenu[2]) { // is id the same as parent_id
                array_push($value, [$id => $submenu]);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                insertSubmenu($id, $value, $submenu); // search deeper
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can process an array recursively but arrays are not recursive

Comment: @Michael It is dangerous to fix what you think are typos in the persons question !!!! If that is the issue you have just obfiscated it completely, and we could now go round and round looking for more complex things all wasting our time

Comment: Is the missing Quote in this line actually in your real code? `0 => ['menu 1, '', -1],`

Comment: I also think `0 => ['menu 1, '', -1], ` should be revised, because it causes wrong formatting on this code. Of course, this code cannot run.

Comment: when you use array like this, it's better to place submenus inside of parent menu. then you can make what you want recursively.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. The missing ' was a typo here so I don't have the typo in my actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because of how you pass `$menu` around. You should be able to use `global`, but your declaration would need to be `global $menu = []`, and then I THINK you have to `global $menu` in EACH of your functions.

IMO, don't use `global`.

Instead pass your `$menu` by reference. You can do that by using an object & objects are always by-reference, or by defining your function like:
`function fillMenu(&$menu, $items)`
Notice the `&` in front of `$menu`. You'd want to declare it this way on all of your functions, then the original array will be passed around, instead of the array being copied for each function call.

Correct me if I'm wrong. I never use `global` and rarely pass by reference, as I use objects... a lot.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php